# How to fix "ImportError: No module named 'x'"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create some test cases and i'm running into this:

> ImportError: No module named bjmusic.controllers.music_c

I'm running music_test.py and my directory structure is the following:

```
BJMusic
├── app.py
└── bjmusic
    ├── controllers
    │   ├── album_c.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main_c.py
    │   ├── main_c.pyc
    │   ├── music_c.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── album_m.py
    │   ├── albuns.txt
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── music_m.py
    │   ├── musics.txt
    │   ├── playlist.py
    │   ├── playlists.txt
    ├── tests
    │   ├── album_test.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── music_test.py
    │   ├── music_test.pyc
    │   └── playlist_test.py
    └── views
        ├── album_v.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main_v.py
        ├── music_v.py
```

My 'music_test.py' file is the following:

```
import unittest
from bjmusic.controllers.music_c import searchMusicsById

class TestAlbums(unittest.Testcase):
    def test_searchMusicsById(self):
        self.assertEqual(bjmusic.controllers.music_c.searchMusicsById(23), {1: ['Michael Jackson', 'Bad', '4:07']})
```

I've searched on stackoverflow and didn't found anything that helped me. I was having the same issue earlier, I believe because of circular importing, but I corrected it in all the files, so I dont think its this.

Answer (score 1):

Add the top-level directory to PYTHONPATH.
If you change directory there before you run it, you can just set "PYTHONPATH=."